# How to Sequentially execute Asynctask in a Loop?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I know there is alot of stuff  `AsyncTask` and i've been exploring for quite some time but still havent found soultion. I have to upload images on FTP server in serialized manner. I know that on and after API 11, `AsyncTask` executes sequentially by default. But, **NOT EXACTLY SEQUENTIAL** ... So far my observations are : only `DoInBackgorund()` method executes sequentially , so if you have N asynctasks being called for execution , their `OnPreExecute()` are called independent of the execution of anyother Asynctask being executed. What i want is complete sequential execution Like this :

ASYNCTASK 1 :

```
OnPreExecute();
DoInBackgorund();
OnPostExecute();
```

Followed By :

ASYNCTASK 2 :

```
OnPreExecute();
DoInBackgorund();
OnPostExecute();
```

Followed By :

ASYNCTASK 2 :

```
OnPreExecute();
DoInBackgorund();
OnPostExecute();
```

... and so on.

Please provide me with some idea, tweak or concept to achieve complete sequential execution of async threads. Dummy code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**  image uploading mechanism is perfectly fine and images are being uploaded. i'am creating instances of `uploadTask` (my `asyncTask` for uploading image) and executing them in loop. Only problem is ; i've to update UI in `OnPreExecute()` of each thread ( to show number of image being uploaded , in `TextView`). This is my problem since `OnPreExecute()`are not being executed sequentially.

Comment: Use publishProgress and onProgressUpdate to replace what you're doing in onPreExecute: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest option: only have one `AsyncTask`, where you process all the work in a single `doInBackground()`, using `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()` to publish per-download results, if needed. I do not know why you think having N non-parallel `AsyncTask` instances is a good idea.

Or: don't use `AsyncTask` at all. Use your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so you have complete control over the characteristics of your jobs. Use an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, Otto, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.) to publish the results on the UI thread.

Or: From `onPostExecute()` of the first `AsyncTask`, start the next `AsyncTask` in your chain.

Comment: the reason for which i dont think parallel execution is a good idea is : i'm uploading images to and FTP server with shared host, we all know that parallel execution of threads slows down the individual thread processing and also create complexities of thread synchronization.

Comment: it wouldn't be parallel execution. it would be serial, within `doInBackground`, within the same thread.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 1st 2 proposed solutions at all :(

Comment: do you mean i should upload say 10 images in single thread ?? i dont suppose you mean that

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd: "do you mean i should upload say 10 images in single thread ?" -- sure. That is the net effect of doing the `AsyncTask` list sequentially. Remember: *you* are the one who is saying that you want sequential behavior. Usually, with network I/O, parallel threads are fine (within reason), as those threads are usually blocking on the network I/O itself and therefore do not consume CPU continuously. But, if you want sequential uploads, that's fine, but then you may as well just use one thread.

Comment: the 1st proposal would be 'completely sequential' as you put it. If you had a single AsyncTask, its `doInBackground` method will upload 1 image at a time - why do you think you need an new asynctask for every image?

Comment: @CommonsWare , alright , if i upload N images in single `DoInBackground() ` execution , i dont think long-running asynctasks are suggested anywhere, and further, i wont be able to update UI until upload of all images complete

Comment: @SamDozor i don't know anything about `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`. so i should better study them first.

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd: "i dont think long-running asynctasks are suggested anywhere" -- personally, I would use an `IntentService`. However, an individual long-running `AsyncTask` is no greater risk than N consecutive sequential shorter-running `AsyncTasks`. "i wont be able to update UI until upload of all images complete" -- use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`, as noted in my answer. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks alot for guidance so far, i'm starting working on your proposal. will accept answer after being done with this. thanks again.

Comment: @CommonsWare though my problem is solved now and everything is perfect, please give my your opinion ; should i upload all images with loop INSIDE `DoInBackground()` or by invoking task.execute() per single image upload ?

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd: I would use `IntentService`. Lacking that, I would use a single `AsyncTask` with the loop inside `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a interface callback on the OnPostExecute()

```
eg.
    //activity
    MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface
    {
     @Override
     public void Task1Complete()
     {
       new StartTask2(getActivity, MyActivity.this).execute();
    }

    //Interface
    public interface MyInterface
    {
     void Task1Complete()
    }

    //AsyncTask1

    public class task1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
      Context ctx;
      MyInterface myInterface;

     public task1(Context _ctx, MyInterface _myInterface)
    {
      this.ctx = _ctx;
      this.myInterface = _myInterface;
    }

    doinbackground{}


    onpostexecute()
    {
       myInterface.Task1Complete();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but above on solved my problem :)